# DataTables: Show custom html code in last column

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

AJAX:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Dashboard",
            "url": "/",
            "icon": "icon-home",
            "child_of": null,
            "show": 1,
            "admin": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Submenu 3",
            "url": "http://stackoverflow.com",
            "icon": null,
            "child_of": null,
            "show": 1,
            "admin": 0
        },
    ]
}
```

JS:

```
$('#table-editable').dataTable({
    "ajax": {
        "url": "/api/menu",
        "type": "GET",
        "headers": {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "id" },
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "url" },
            { "data": "icon" },
            { "data": "child_of" },
            { "data": "show" },
            { "data": "admin" }
        ]
});
```

HTML:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>URL</th>
        <th>Icon</th>
        <th>Parent</th>
        <th>Show</th>
        <th>Admin</th>
        <th class="text-right">Action</th> //button for edit,delete row.
    </tr>
</thead>
```

I can see the data from AJAX in DataTable. But the last column remains empty. It is for showing edit, remove buttons.

This is the html code of two buttons (edit, remove). I want to add this code in last column. It should appear in every row with the data recieved from AJAX. :

```
<a class="edit btn btn-sm btn-default" href="javascript:;"><i class="icon-note"></i></a> <a class="delete btn btn-sm btn-danger" href="javascript:;"><i class="icons-office-52"></i></a>
```

How can I do it?

### Solution

Added this to the last column.

```
{
    "data": null,
     defaultContent: '<a class="edit btn btn-sm btn-default" href="javascript:;"><i class="icon-note"></i></a> <a class="delete btn btn-sm btn-danger" href="javascript:;"><i class="icons-office-52"></i></a>'
}
```

Comment: Your script is malformed. You have `"columns": [` *inside* the `ajax` literal, it should be *outside*.

Comment: @davidkonrad updated the question. Please answer it now again.

Comment: Add a  `{ "data":  null }` to the `columns` section.